# Automating angular project versioning using standard-version npm package

Tags: angular, versioning, angular-library

I have an angular workspace with the structure below

```
- AngularProject
    - projects
        - lib1
           - lib
           - package.json
    - src
        - app
    - package.json
```

lib1 is a package that is to be published to npm.

I want to use the standard-version npm package to automate versioning in this project. Is there a way the
`standard-version` 
CLI command can update the version in the `package.json` files in both the root directory and the lib1 directory.

I have tried using the `standard-version` CLI command but it only updates the `package.json` in the root directory.

**Expectation:**

The `package.json` files in both the root directory and lib1 directory should be updated using `standard-version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to create a .versionrc file as shown below in the root directory and add a list of bump files (i.e files containing the project version).

```
// .versionrc
{
  "bumpFiles": [
    {
      "filename": "first package.json location",
      // The `json` updater assumes the version is available under a `version` key in the provided JSON document.
      "type": "json"
    },
     {
      "filename": "second package.json location",
      // The `json` updater assumes the version is available under a `version` key in the provided JSON document.
      "type": "json"
    }
  ]
}
```

For a better understanding, check out the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version#can-i-use-standard-version-for-additional-metadata-files-languages-or-version-files)